# Http Request not seen in Fiddler ends up with NoHttpResponseException

Tags: httpclient

I am trying to send Http Requests from Android phone using Apache HttpClient to a server routing my requests via Fiddler. For certain requests, the DefaultHttpClient.execute throws a NoHttpResponseException, but this particular request is not seen in the fiddler at all.

The same thing happens if i direct my traffic without Fiddler but directly over wifi. The code for execute works fine generally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by handling the NoHttpResponseException and re-sending the request. When the same requests gets sent again, it goes through fine.
I would be interested to know the root cause of this issue - but for the time being this works for me.